# Express a function in mathematical notation

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, notation

I am familiar in reading mathematical notation but I have troubles when I try to use it. I have the next question. What I want is to express in math notation, all the linear functions that goes from $R^2$ to R, how could i do that? The option that i thought is:

$f:R^2 \to R$ $\quad$ where $\quad f(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha f(x)+\beta f(y)$ | $ x,y\in R^2 \land \alpha,\beta\in R$

Is this correct or may be am I omitting or doing something wrong?

Comment: Firstly you use same $f$ for left  and right sides: on left it is function with $2$ variables, but on right it have $1$ variable. Then you need definition for $f(x,y)$ without $\alpha, \beta$ and then proof for linearity of it.

Comment: Since $f$ is a function, you have to have that $$f(2 \times 1, 4 \times 3) = f(1 \times 2, 3 \times 4),$$ because $$(2 \times 1, 4 \times 3) = (1 \times 2, 3 \times 4).$$  Assuming that you use $g(x)$ to represent the **other** function, $$\text{Is, for example} ~\{ ~[2 \times g(1)] + [4 \times g(3)] ~\} ~~\text{equal to} ~~\{ ~[1 \times g(2)] + [3 \times g(4)] ~\} ~?$$

Comment: I have done a couple of changes because I had some typos, forgive me.

Answer (score 1):

You could first give your child a name. For instance define
$$
L(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R):=\{f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R\vert\,f\text{ is linear}\}.
$$

Recall that a map $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is called linear if
$$
f(v+\lambda\cdot w)=f(v)+\lambda\cdot f(w) \forall  v,w\in\mathbb R^2,\lambda\in\mathbb R.
$$

You could also write
$$
L(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R)=\{f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R,\, (x,y)\mapsto \alpha x+\beta y\,\vert\,\alpha,\beta \in\mathbb R\}
$$
However this is something that requires a proof starting from the definition of $L(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think that I do not understand your comment regarding f(x,y), I mean, may be I forgot in the original problem yo specify that: $f(\alpha x + \beta y)=\alpha f(x) + \beta f(y)$ where $x,y \in R^2 and \alpha, \beta \in R$. That is, I want to express to general property of a function to be consider as linear, but where the function goes from $R^2$ to $R$. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: @Ibai Ah I see; I misunderstoof your question. I edited my answer. I think its this definition of "linear" you were looking for, right? If this is unclear to you, you could compare it to the defintion of a linear map between vector spaces.

Comment: Yes! That is what I was looking for, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that $\operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb R^2,\Bbb R)$ is quite a standard notation for your set:
$$\operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb R^2,\Bbb R):=\{f\colon\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R\mid f\text{ is linear}\}$$

Comment: I see. And it is possible instead off writting f is linear to do it in math notation? Thank you.

Comment: Well, the formal definiton of linear is basically as you and the other aswerer have written already. I don't think there's another, more succint way.